# Plot subnetwork / subgraph after selecting nodes with VisNetwork in R

Tags: r, graph

I have built a network successfully with VisNetwork, and deployed it with Shiny.  My question is as follows.  Once I click on a node, it highlights the nearest neighbors to the nth degree (default = 1). Is is possible to draw a sub-network with only a node and its neighbors, and then return to the entire network by clicking off the node?

Thank you,

So with the code below, I create network, enable nearest neighbor selection and I can select the nodes.  I am not sure how to redraw only the sub-network.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$network_proxy <- renderVisNetwork({
visNetwork(my.nodes, my.edges, 
           height = "100%", width = "100%",
           main = "") %>%
  #visExport() %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, degree = 1, hover = T, algorithm = "hierarchical"),
             nodesIdSelection = list(enabled = TRUE, selected = "First Data", style = 'width: 200px; height: 26px;
                               background: #f8f8f8;
                               color: darkblue;
                               border:none;
                               outline:none;' ),
             selectedBy = list(variable = "Role", selected ="", 
                      multiple =TRUE, style = 'width: 200px; height: 26px;
                               background: #f8f8f8;
                               color: darkblue;
                               border:none;
                               outline:none;' ),
             autoResize = TRUE)%>% 
  visInteraction(keyboard = TRUE,
                 navigationButtons = TRUE,
                 dragView = TRUE,
                 dragNodes = TRUE,                 
                 hideEdgesOnDrag = TRUE,
                 tooltipDelay = 0,
                 hover = TRUE,
                 hoverConnectedEdges =FALSE,
                 multiselect = TRUE)%>%      
  visEvents(hoverNode = "function(nodes){
            Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id',nodes);
            ;}",
            select = "function(nodes){
            Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id',nodes);
            ;}")
})

  output$shiny_return <- renderPrint({
   if(!is.null(input$current_node_id)){
     input$current_node_id
   }
  })
} #end server

ui <- fluidPage(  
  mainPanel(
  visNetworkOutput("network_proxy"),
  verbatimTextOutput("shiny_return")    
  )  
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `degree`, you can set a high number (equal to number of nodes for example) and then get the entire full network highlight.

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% 
   visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = TRUE, degree = 100))
```

Actually, the other part of the network is color in gray, but I'll add a new options soon to control that, and so hidden some part of network if wanted. (https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/98)

Comment: thanks for thr answer. Any chance you could please look at a visnetwork question I had? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669941/adding-additional-information-to-a-visnetwork?  Thank you